# Error in compilation of scala file in play

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Scala file and I am using Play Framework 2.0.4 to compile it. Here is a part of it

```
import play.api.templates.Html;
import play.api.templates.Txt;
import securesocial.controllers.Registration.RegistrationInfo;
import securesocial.controllers.TemplatesPlugin.
import securesocial.core.{SecuredRequest, SocialUser};
import play.api.data.Form;
import securesocial.core.Identity;
import securesocial.core.SecureSocial._;
import securesocial.controllers.PasswordChange.ChangeInfo;
```

At compile time I get this error

`identifier expected but 'import' found.`

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 4):

Could it be `import securesocial.controllers.TemplatesPlugin.`: the trailing dot?
Either remove the dot or make it `import securesocial.controllers.TemplatesPlugin._`